# Select results and use result value as column

Tags: postgresql

I have such query in postgres:

```
  WITH results AS (
                    select distinct id, type from m.errors
                  )
    select distinct t.ag_id, q.type, q.id
    from (select distinct id, type from results where type = results.type) q
    inner join m.full f on f.[results.type]_id = q.id
```

`results.type` can be e.g. book, newspaper, paper etc
based on it I need my inner join to look like this:

`inner join m.full f on f.book_id = q.id`

`inner join m.full f on f.paper_id = q.id`

etc. is it possible to do it? I can't figure it out. Or should I use `case` here?

Comment: Postgres or MySQL? Please remove the irrelevant tag. Also, please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977). By the way, you don't want to randomly sprinkle `distinct` in your queries.

Comment: Postgres @mustaccio

Comment: "from results where type = results.type"   Are you comparing the type column to itself?

Comment: Please provide a dbfiddle.uk ASAP.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328). Also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70289930/select-results-and-use-result-value-as-column)